# Difference between opencv and numpy resize functions

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-resizing

It is not clear to me the difference between resizing a numpy array using `numpy.resize` or using `cv2.resize`.

While implementing a CNN for image processing, I had a massive memory leak when using Numpy's function to resize a `800x800` array to `10x10`, which I managed to solve by using `cv2.resize` instead, so I wonder what is the different behavior of this function that may have solved the problem.

Comment: "memory leak"? that term doesn't apply to python/numpy. explain what you mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you compare the documentation of [`cv2.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) with the one of [`np.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) you will realize that they do completely differen things. The numpy function rearranges the data to fit the give output shape, possibly repeating or discarding data. The opencv function on the other hand is for rescaling images to a different resolution. They basically have nothing in common.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I read the documentations but it is not clear to me how `np.resize` operates to "shrink" the array. If it discards some arguments of the array, then  which criteria is used? And thus why when reducing the shape in every dimension won't the effect be the same as with `cv2.resize`?

Comment: `np.resize` is clear it isn't designed for images.  Read the `[source]` to see what actually does.  In your case it will return a (10,10) array with the first 100 values your array. No interpolation, sampling, averaging, just a small part.  Test functions like this on small cases where you can actually examine the result.